# Program not returning expected results

Tags: python

So I've written a program to encrypt a message using the Caesar shift algorithm. Here is the code:

```
MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26

def getMode():
    while True:
        print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
        mode = input().lower()
        if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():
            return mode
        else:
            print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')

def getMessage():
    print('Enter your message:')
    return input()

def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Enter the value you want your message to be shifted by. You can choose anything from 1 to 26.')
        key = int(input())
        if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
            return key

def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):
    if mode[0] == 'd':
        key = -key
        translated = ''

    for symbol in message:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

    if symbol.isupper():
        if num > ord('Z'):
            num -= 26
    elif num < ord('A'):
        num += 26
    elif symbol.islower():
        if num > ord('z'):
            num -= 26
    elif num < ord('a'):
        num += 26

        translated += chr(num)
    else:
        translated += symbol
        return translated

mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()
print('Your translated text is:')
print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

Here is what happens when I run it in Visual Studio Code:

"Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?
encrypt

Enter your message: 
silver

Enter the value you want your message to be shifted by. You can choose anything from 1 to 26. 
3

Your translated text is:
None"

The problem is regardless of what message is entered for encrpytion, I always get the same answer of 'none' instead of the encrypted message.

Does anyone have any idea on how I can fix this?

Comment: can you do a quick debug and print mode, message and key before calling the last print?

Comment: You want to see the contents of mode, message and key?

Comment: I want to understand what's being fed to your translation function, yes. I understand you take user inputs, but define a base case and check what's being used as inputs for `getTranslatedMessage`

Comment: as far as I can tell, it asks the user for inputs, gets to def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key): and prints none as the answer.

Comment: do this: `print(mode), print(message), print(key)` before the last print

Comment: still getting nothing besides "none" unfortunately

Comment: Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: what do you mean? you get none for the three of them?

Comment: Nothing is returned for each of the three variables. not even "none" like I get for the translated message. It doesn't print anything at all.

Comment: @JoshuaLankamp are the conditionals below `symbol.isalpha()` supposed to be inside the for loop?

Comment: Yes, they are meant to encrypt each character of a word in a user inputted message one by one. Therefore they need to loop to encrypt the whole message. @JackMoody

Comment: For future reference, check out https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your issue is completely in your indenting, there were sections that were supposed to be in your initial if statement that were not.

With python you have to be very careful with indenting since there are no brackets that control the conditionals.

```py
MAX_KEY_SIZE = 26

def getMode():
    while True:
        print('Do you wish to encrypt or decrypt a message?')
        mode = input().lower()
        if mode in 'encrypt e decrypt d'.split():
            return mode
        else:
            print('Enter either "encrypt" or "e" or "decrypt" or "d".')

def getMessage():
    print('Enter your message:')
    return input()

def getKey():
    key = 0
    while True:
        print('Enter the value you want your message to be shifted by. You can choose anything from 1 to 26.')
        key = int(input())
        if (key >= 1 and key <= MAX_KEY_SIZE):
            return key

def getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key):
    translated = ''

    if mode[0] == 'd':
        key = -key

    for symbol in message:
        if symbol.isalpha():
            num = ord(symbol)
            num += key

            if symbol.isupper():
                if num > ord('Z'):
                    num -= 26
            elif num < ord('A'):
                num += 26
            elif symbol.islower():
                if num > ord('z'):
                    num -= 26
            elif num < ord('a'):
                num += 26

            translated += chr(num)
        else:
            translated += symbol
    return translated

mode = getMode()
message = getMessage()
key = getKey()
print('Your translated text is:')
print(getTranslatedMessage(mode, message, key))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! That fixed the issue.